# Is there a way to change the size, color and shape of a point?

Tags: python, colors, size, point

Any chance I can change the color and size of the points and make them look like this: ○   on python?

my code as of right now is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DATA
L = 0.1 #m, length of arm of cross
t = L/2 #m, thickness

# VECTORS OF COORDINATES OF THE CROSS
X = np.array([L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2, t/2, L, L])
Y = np.array([t/2, t/2, L, L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2])

# PLOT
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.plot(X,Y,color='C1', linewidth=2.5)
ax.axis('equal')

point_x = [L - t/2, -L + t/2, 0, 0]
point_y = [0, 0, L-t/2, -L + t/2]

points = ax.scatter(point_x, point_y)
axis_off = ax.axis('off')
```

and looks like:

[image]

I am looking towards changing the color size and shape of the blue dots on each end, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `scatter` into a `plot`, you have more freedom on the marker size:

```
points = ax.plot(point_x, point_y, ".", ms=50)
```

Also, you can chose the marker shape from here:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers.

Answer (score 0):

In `scatter` you can change the size through the parameter `s`, the color through `c` and the shape through `marker`. If I understood correctly and you want empty circles as markers, it can be obtained in this way:

```
points = ax.scatter(point_x, point_y, facecolors='none', edgecolors='red', s=200)
```